# Where did the slang usages of "cool" come from?

Tags: slang, history

I see and hear two general slang usages of cool - one meaning *great* (illustrated by **a** and **b** below), and one meaning *acceptable/okay* (illustrated by **c** and **d**).  The following are Dictionary.com's four (read: two) definitions of the slang *[cool](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cool)*:

> **14.** *Slang*
>   **a.** great; fine; excellent: *a real cool comic.*
>   **b.** characterized by great facility; highly skilled or clever: *cool maneuvers on the parallel bars.*
>   **c.** socially adept: *It's not cool to arrive at a party too early.*
>   **d.** acceptable; satisfactory; okay: *If you want to stay late, that's cool.*

Why did *cool* come to mean *great* or *acceptable*? Also, can anyone find some early usages?  The biggest clue I have is this (from Dictionary.com):

> Slang use for "fashionable" is 1933, originally Black English, said to have been popularized in jazz circles by tenor saxophonist Lester Young.

Googling *Lester Young 1933 "cool"*, etc., did not yield me any fruit.

Comment: I have always assumed it was an extension of cool meaning aloof. Since if you are aloof it can give you a certain air of superiority that some people respect (others find infuriating). It's certainly how I imagine James Dean.

Comment: Man, that's an aloof motorcycle!  And by the way, are you aloof with me having the car tonight?

Comment: Artis Leon Ivey, Jr, also known as Aloofio

Comment: Thanks and no :D Cool's meaning has evolved, obviously :) But if you are aloof then things don't seem to bother you, which seems to be the root of being cool. (to me)

Comment: That usage came from Canada -- we live among icebergs and igloos up here!  ;-)

Comment: I always thought *cool* developed from the Swedish word for "fun", *kul*, which sounds kind of like *cool*. In the English language there are many words that come from other languages, so as a child I just assumed since they sounded so similar *cool* must have been changed and adapted over the years. I'm probably wrong, but I've always wondered about it. Just my two cents' worth.

Comment: I can't attest to actual origin, but it always seemed to me to mean a person who is not jittery or jumpy, a person who stays calm under pressure, especially when the "heat" is on. (Like a criminal being questioned by law enforcement.) Then, "cool" morphed from "cool under pressure" to "ok", "good" or "excellent."

Comment: The explanation I've heard several times is that it came from an exaggeration of the jazz term "hot".  Since whatever was being described was "hotter" than "hot", "so hot that it's cool" was said as a sort of hyperbole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary writes:

> Originally in African-American usage: (as a general term of approval) admirable, excellent. Cf. hot adj. 12c.
>   Popularized among jazz musicians and enthusiasts in the late 1940s

The first example they give is from the 1930s:

> 1933    Z. N. Hurston in Story Aug. 63   And whut make it so cool, he got money 'cumulated. And womens give it all to 'im.

The entry refers to *hot* as a comparison--the main entry is "Characterized by intensity or energy, in a positive or neutral sense (cf. sense A. 9); exciting, fast, successful, etc." and the related sense is:

> colloq. (orig. U.S.). Extremely good, splendid; very skilled, knowledgeable, or successful. Also with on and a specified subject or activity.

This is first noted from the 1800s:

> 1845    in G. W. Harris High Times & Hard Times (1967) 52,   I am a hot hand at the location of capital letters and punctuation.

So, it looks like *cool* developed to mean the same thing as the earlier slang *hot* in African American English. There is no explanation of why this occurred.

Comment: Sooo, no explanation, eh?  I might have known :)

Comment: @drɱ65δ I suspect it could be something similar to using antonyms because it was a counter-culture, but I don't want to put out conjectures I can't back up.

Comment: Then what did you just do?  :)

Comment: @drɱ65δ Didn't put it in my answer, that's for sure :]

Comment: I imagine that it can be explained in the same way that 'bad', 'wicked', etc. (and for that matter, 'terrific') took on positive slang connotations (the latter is probably thought of more as colloquial now). Unfortunately, I don't really know how that is...

Answer (score 0):

It seems incredible there is no connection to the French term **sang-froid** (which simply means sang == blood, froid == cold ... cold blooded).

Consider perhaps the Southern/New Orleans etc. connection to African-Americabn culture.